# Invalid calling object IE

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer

In FF and Chrome i can set the *this* value to the location object using bind, with the following code

```
locationFacade ={
reload: location.reload.bind(location)
} 
locationFacade.reload();
```

Or I can use apply

```
locationFacade ={   
    reload: function(){
        location.reload.apply(location,arguments);  }
}
locationFacade.reload();
```

However in IE 9 I keep getting **"Invalid calling object"** when calling *locationFacade.reload();* I havent tested every IE but issue happens in IE 11 also. Apply and bind are both supported in IE [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/4zc42wh1(v=vs.94).aspx) and [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/gg622930(v=vs.85).aspx)

Comment: Why you didn't use only **location.reload()**?

Comment: I want to pass in any arguments that the locationFacade.reload received. For example, if I wanted to create a similar function for location.replace.apply(location,arguments) I also receive the same error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This problem seems to be a bug of IE. I tested lots of functions in IE11 (document.writeln, window.alert, etc.), and all of them could be bound, except the members of `location`. This workaround might help:

```
locationFacade = {
    reload: window.navigate ?
            window.navigate.bind(window, location.href) :
            location.reload.bind(location)
}
```

Comment: nice workaround, thanks! except you must have meant location.href, thier is no location.url

Comment: You are welcome. The same technique works for `assign`, but I could not find a replacement for `replace`.

Comment: console.log has the same problem too on IE 11 (.0.9600.18314)